# Number of ways to fill 4 cells in a $4 \times 4$ array under constraints

Tags: permutations, permutation-matrices

Two undistinguishable letters $a$ and two undistinguishable letters $b$ are filled into $16$ cells of a square matrix. It is required that each cell contains at most $1$ letter and each row or column cannot contain the same letters. What is the number of ways which the matrix can be filled in?

My attempt:

I considered the case of first placing the two '$a$' s in $\frac{\binom{16}{1}\binom{9}{1}}{2} =72$ ways
and then the two '$b$'s in also $72$ ways.

Now we need to find the overlapping cases.

$(i)$

In the same cell we have got $72 +$ the case where one $b$ is in the same cell as that of $a$ and the other $b$ is in it's proper place. This is where I am getting confused.

Please help me out.

Comment: use `\displaystyle\binom{x}{y}` for the output $\displaystyle\binom{x}{y}$.

Comment: You mean you have two undistinguishable letters $a$ and  two undistinguishable letters $b$. Right ?

Comment: @JeanMarie, it's my fault, I edited it. I'll correct it.

Comment: I have taken the liberty to modify your title (and your tags) into something that reflects the content of the question. Do you agree ?

Comment: Ok no problem it's fine

Answer (score 2):

I think you've got a good idea. Let's say we start with $a$ and $b$ in a common cell, and place $a$ and $b$ freely in other cells that aren't in the same row/column, but also so that the second $a$ and $b$ end up in distinct cells. There are $16$ places to put the $a$ and $b$ together, then $9$ cells to place the second $a$, then $8$ cells to place the second $b$. In total,
$$16 \times 9 \times 8 = 1152.$$
We also need to exclude the cases where both pairs of $a$ and $b$ end up together, which is simply $72$, as you calculated previously. So, the total should be
$$72^2 - 1152 - 72 = 3960.$$

Comment: Thanks @Daniel.